# NSTextField How to Set NSAttributedString's TextStyle property

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I am trying to programmatically create a NSTextField that has the `NSFont.TextStyle.headline` font style. This font can also be set from the `font` drop down menu in the storyboard.

However, when I do the following:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : NSFont.TextStyle.headline]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: product.url, attributes: attributes)
let textLabel = NSTextField(labelWithAttributedString: attributedString)
```

My app crashes with the following error:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8064f918
```

Comment: A style is not a font. See [NSFont.TextStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/textstyle/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to get the corresponding font associated with the text style.

> Pass these constants to preferredFont(forTextStyle:options:) or preferredFontDescriptor(forTextStyle:options:) to retrieve the corresponding font or font descriptor.

Therefore:

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : NSFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: NSFont.TextStyle.headline, options: [:])]
```